# Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, jsp

Actually it works perfectly in my local set up. However, it is throwing errors in production server.

Here is the details of the errors:

ERROR [InsertTag] ServletException in '/web/pages/exportAppInspectionDetails.jsp': Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 89 in the generated java file

The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 89 in the generated java file
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Comment: please provide environment details of your local and prod, like java version and tomcat version etc.

Comment: SEE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files for how to do JSP properly

Comment: I am using java version "1.6.0_20" and tomcat version 6.0.47

Answer (score 3):

Solution to this given at following link
Make sure that you don't use spring-MVC like framework where object mapping is used. There must be some other way to manage that.

https://support.assetbank.co.uk/hc/en-gb/articles/115005208888-How-do-I-fix-a-65535-bytes-limit-Stacktrace-